# python3 app on Heroku: Application Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

My code:
https://github.com/zxq2233/zmirror
I have deployed my python website on heroku, but when I visit the page, I see a generic heroku "application error" message.

My Procfile contains this line:

```
web: python wsgi.py
```

Comment: I've not used Heroku and I can't answer this question, but you're asking us to help you by linking to your entire codebase and telling us you're getting a very non-descript error. Is it possible to find more detailed error traces in log files and/or paste excerpts of your codebase where you think the problematic code is most likely to be located?

Comment: Run `heroku logs` on the command line and show us your output. This will contain the actual application errors if you have debugging enabled in your application code.